# Contruct cumulative sum for duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am looking for formula in Excel to construct cumulative sum for the duplicates.

```
 Item   Value   Cumulative sum
 -----------------------------
 A        3          3            
 A1       4          4
 A1       7         11
 A1       5         16
 B1      20         20
 B1       4         24
 C        6          6
 D       10         10
 E        8          8
 E        7         15
```

The table given shows the cumulative for the duplicates in Column 1(Item).
I need excel formula to construct this for my calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Break problems like these down step-by-step.
(Assume your data are in `A1:C11` (`col C` is empty except for the header).)

1. To calculate a cumulative sum, you just add the current value in `col B` to the previous value in `col C`. This is simply `=C1+B2` in `C2`, `=C2+B3` in `C3`, etc.
2. To evaluate whether you are in the same group of `Item`, you can simply test whether `A2=A1`, `A3=A2`, etc.
3. To reset your cumulative sum when the group changes, you can use an `IF()` function. In (2), you have a logical condition. In (1), you have an operation to perform if the condition is true. If the condition is *not* true, you want to reset the cumulative sum, which is simply the value of `col B` in the current row.

So to put it together (in `C2`):

```
=IF(A2=A1, C1+B2, B2)
```

Then fill down.